# Pandas swap multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It is possible to change multilevel index in pandas

From:

```
Disc1 A .
      B .
      C .
Disc2 A .
      B .
      C .
```

To:

```
A  Disc1 .
   Disc2 .
B  Disc1 .
   Disc2 .
C  Disc1 .
   Disc2 .
```

MWE below. The column `'is'` data is the same for column and these values are not important for the task

```
import pandas as pd
dicts = {'is': {
  ('Disc1',
   'A'): True,
  ('Disc1',
   'B'): True,
  ('Disc1',
   'C'): True,
  ('Disc1',
   'D'): True,
  ('Disc2', 'A'): True,
  ('Disc2', 'B'): True,
  ('Disc2',
   'C'): True,
  ('Disc2',
   'ОD'): True}}
pd.DataFrame(dicts)
```

Comment: `df.swaplevel()`

Comment: @sammywemmy Unfortunantly, swaplevel() breeds second index

Comment: `df.swaplevel().sort_index()`?